# how to access JSON object and insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, json

i would like to access an JSON format which is different from what i usually get.

Usually i get JSON like below :

```
{
kind: "youtube#searchListResponse",
etag: ""stbstbsts"",
nextPageToken: "CAUQAA",
pageInfo: {
totalResults: 1000000,
resultsPerPage: 5
},
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#searchResult",
etag: ""pWoriJ5rlTq3315otdsHvMzLHR4"",
id: {
kind: "youtube#channel",
channelId: "UCbFnGyIcAhDrj-90OzvI7kw"
},
snippet: {
publishedAt: "2013-07-11T06:09:13.000Z",
channelId: "UCbFnGyIcAhDrj-90OzvI7kw",
title: "Oh My Disney",
description: "Videos for Disney lovers, by Disney lovers.",
thumbnails: {
default: {
url: "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-RpvvvIX2cL8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/22QzVC_ihE4/s512-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
},
medium: {
url: "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-RpvvvIX2cL8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/22QzVC_ihE4/s512-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
},
high: {
url: "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-RpvvvIX2cL8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/22QzVC_ihE4/s512-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
}
},
channelTitle: "OhMyDisney",
liveBroadcastContent: "none"
}
},
{
kind: "youtube#searchResult",
etag: ""u4/3yClYSRlqGt3fuhXIOAwxFZWxB4"",
id: {
kind: "youtube#video",
videoId: "y8tDrJj-uyQ"
},
...
```

And use

```
$arr = array();
foreach (json_decode($response) as $item){
  $post = $item->snippet->description;

  $arr[] = array(
           "post" => htmlspecialchars($post),
           );
/* script to insert database here */
}
```

From above JSON output i can access it and insert it to database.
Now, we get to my question. I have this code.

My Code :

```
$appear = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=Disney";
function get_curl($url) {
    if(function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    } else {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }
}
$response = get_curl($appear);
```

OUTPUT :

```
[
  "disney",
  [
     "disney store",
     "disney",
     "disney world",
     "disneyland",
     "disney cruise",
     "disney movies",
     "disney channel",
     "disney games",
     "disneyland paris",
     "disney on ice"
  ]
]
```

Aim :

```
"disney store" -> insert this word to the db
"disney"       -> insert this word to the db 
"disney world" -> insert this word to the db
```

How to do it?

Comment: decode it and just access the values like any normal array, from there either just use mysqli or PDO and just use the API along with your insert query. and better, use prepared statements. just google it, there's no shortage of info in that topic `pdo insert db php` or just use the search here in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the value you are looking for, I leave you to add the database INSERT/UPDATE code

```
echo $response['disney']['disney store'];
echo $response['disney']['disney'];
echo $response['disney']['disney world'];
```

Comment: for ($i=0;$i<count($respone['disney']);$i++){ $res = $response['disney'][$i]; echo $res; }